# Azure devops Yaml Synapse workspace deployment@2 task tries to deploy to wrong resource group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-synapse

To deploy the Synapse workspace I'm using the Synapse workspace deployment@2 yaml task. This is my code:

```
          - task: Synapse workspace deployment@2
            displayName: Synapse workspace deployment
            inputs:
              operation: 'deploy'
              TemplateFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/extracted/TemplateForWorkspace.json'
              ParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/extracted/TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json'
              azureSubscription: 'xxxxx Service Connection'
              resourceGroupName: 'xxxxx-P-xxxxx'
              TargetWorkspaceName: 'xxxxx-p-xxxxx'
              DeleteArtifactsNotInTemplate: false
              DeployManagedPrivateEndpoints: false
              OverrideArmParameters: |
                KeyVault_properties_typeProperties_baseUrl: https://xxxxx${{ parameters.environment }}xxxxx.net
                Datalake_properties_typeProperties_url: https://xxxxx${{ parameters.environment }}xxxxx.net
```

In my pipeline I'm replacing the resourceGroupName and svc by using a parameter. For now I've hardcoded the values. The problem is that this step tries to deploy to the wrong resourcegroup. The subscription has an Acc and Prd resourcegroup and it tries to find the prd Synapse workspace in the acc resourcegroup instead of the prd resourcegroup.

This is part of the default logging of the yaml task:

```
Workspace info url:  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxx-A-xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/xxxx-p-xxxx?api-version=2019-06-01-preview
```

This is the error, which makes sense cause the A resource group has no P Synapse workspace:

```
Failed to fetch workspace info, status: 404; status message: Not Found
deploy operation failed
An error occurred during execution: Error: Get workspace location error: Failed to fetch workspace info Not Found
```

This is the output of the logging after enabling debug mode:

```
##[debug]resourceGroupName='xxxxx-P-xxxxx'
##[debug]f74808a2-2f58-4031-80fe-1eebd68655be auth param scope = /subscriptions/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/resourcegroups/'xxxxx-A-xxxxx'
##[debug]f74808a2-2f58-4031-80fe-1eebd68655be auth scheme = ServicePrincipal
##[debug]f74808a2-2f58-4031-80fe-1eebd68655be auth scheme = ServicePrincipal
##[debug]f74808a2-2f58-4031-80fe-1eebd68655be data subscriptionid = xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx
##[debug]f74808a2-2f58-4031-80fe-1eebd68655be data subscriptionname = xxx-xxx-Pxxx-1
```

The logging shows that the auth param scope is pointed towards the Acc resource group. I think that this is causing the issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

From your Yaml Sample and the error message, you are using the azure Subscription service connection.

The service connection is Azure Resource Manager Service Connection.

When you create the service connection, you may specify the Resource Group in the service connection. Then if you use the service connection in Synapse workspace deployment task, it will use the wrong Resource Group.

For example:

[image]

To solve this issue, you can modify the service connection and select the correct Resource Group. Or you can create an Azure Resource Manager Service Connection at Azure Subscription level(Not Specify the Resource Group).

For example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is not the fix. Our svc is already at subscription level. The logging shows that it's using the right subscription. What I can do is trying to create a new svc and point it towards the prod resource group.